# JSONObject response null

Tags: android, json, android-volley, response

I'm trying to send a simply `JSON request` using `Volley JsonObjectRequest`.
After getting the `JSON response`, I would like to update a value called `valoreConvertito`, but the JSON response is `null` and consequently `valoreConvertito` remains zero.

```
private void convertiREST(final Double valoreDaConvertire, String valuta){

    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url =COMPLETEURL;

    valoreConvertito = 0.0;

    JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            Log.e("Rest response    ", response.toString());
                            valoreConvertito = response.getJSONObject("quotes").getDouble("valuta");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Rest response", error.toString());
                    }
                });
        queue.add(objectRequest);
    }
```

I've even followed the suggestions in another post ([Volley JsonObjectRequest response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509120/volley-jsonobjectrequest-response)) but I still got JSON response null.

Using the debugger it seems that the program doesn't enter neither in `onResponse nor` in `ErrorListener`.

Comment: where you are adding the request to the queue?

Comment: Edit the question with the row "queue.add(objectRequest);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the row `queue.add(objectRequest);` I notice in Logcat the `HTTP traffic not permitted` error and I've solved my issue following [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted) post.